# Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 7 having partitioned before hand

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

Prior to Ubuntu installation I partitioned my drive with the Windows Disk Manager, created unallocated space of around 30gb, then proceeded to boot into the Ubuntu cd.

However, during installation I got to a point where It asked me ''Install alongside Windows 7'' or ''Something else''.

After a quick search it seemed like everybody suggested the first choice.

Installation was completed but, after restarting, I only had one choice to boot into which was Ubuntu. So I think It erased my previous Windows install.

I just deleted everything and Installed Windows again, so I could give it another try. But how do I fix this? Is the correct choice ''Something else'' if I already partitioned my drive before hand?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't erase Windows. The grub menu didn't show up at boot for you to select Windows.

Here what you need to do:

Turn on your computer

At boot, press down the shift key.

Then you will be greeted by the grub menu. Windows should be one of your boot options. Select Windows.

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: So Ubuntu will automatically install in the unallocated space partition?

Also, at some point it asked me something about ''UEFI'' but I just clicked on go back because I wasnt sure about that.

Comment: Yes. Just follow all of the steps after clicking "Install alongside Windows 7 or Something else'', and everything will work just fine.